# Ansible playbook for Cisco Nexus fails with nxapi in provider

Tags: ansible, nexus, cisco

I have not been able to get this playbook working. I am trying to use the 'nxapi' provider method. I have nxapi setup on the target devices. I have a group_vars file with the following settings:

```
ansible_connection: local
ansible_network_os: nxos
ansible_user: user
ansible_password: password
```

The playbook code is:

```
- name: nxos_facts module
  hosts: "{{ myhosts }}"
  vars:
    ssh:
      host: "{{ myhosts }}"
      username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      transport: cli
    nxapi:
      host: "{{ myhosts }}"
      username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      transport: nxapi
      use_ssl: yes
      validate_certs: no
      port: 8443

  tasks:


    - name: nxos_facts nxapi
      nxos_facts:
        provider: "{{ nxapi }}"

When I debug the failed playbook, I see this line:
 ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: < MY USER  NAME >

It seems like the Playbook is not using the variables in the group_vars file , which specify a specific user to connect to the nxapi service on the switch.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can't add a comment due to lack of rep*

Make sure your group_vars match a child group in your host file. (Can't tell from your question)

host file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    SWITCH1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.1
  children:
    group1:
      hosts:
        SWITCH1:
```

You can then have your Group variables in one of 2 files, **all.yml** or **group1.yml**